# Show notification function not being triggered even after push event listener being called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

Using public and private key pair trying to send push notification on web, In this file I'm getting push notification details in service worker file but the thing is self registration show notification function not being called event after push event being triggered.

```
var url = 'token url';
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                subscription_id: Math.random(),
                url: 'deliverable url'
            })
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error();
            }

            // Examine the text in the response  
            return response.json().then(function (data) {
                if (data.error || !data.notification) {
                    console.log('The API returned an error.', data.error);
                    throw new Error();
                }
                console.log('first');
                var title = data.notification.title;
                var message = data.notification.message;
                var icon = data.notification.icon;
                var image = data.notification.image;
                var not_url = data.notification.url;
                return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                    body: message,
                    icon: icon,
                    image: image,
                    data: {
                        url: not_url
                    }
                });
                console.log('second');
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Unable to retrieve data', err);
            var title = 'An error occurred';
            var message = 'We were unable to get the information for this push message';
            var icon = 'img/pwa.jpg';
            var notificationTag = 'notification-error';
            return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                body: message,
                icon: icon,
                tag: notificationTag
            });
        })
    );
});
```